# How to catch dragend event in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable

I'm trying to catch the dragend event in JavaScript for a draggable DIV.
The dragend event is not fired at all, why ? and how to solve this ?
PS, I'm using .draggable() method from: jQuery UI 1.9.2

Here's my code: http://jsfiddle.net/vBMav/

HTML:

```
<div id="divId"> ... </div>
```

CSS:

```
#divId {
    background-color: #000000;
    color: #ffffff;
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
}
```

Javascript:

```
$('#divId').draggable(); 

$('#divId')
    .bind('dragstart', function(){ $("#divId").text("drag start"); })
    .bind('drag',      function(){ $("#divId").text("dragging");   })
    .bind('dragend',   function(){ $("#divId").text("drag ended"); });
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try using `dragstop` instead of `dragend`

```js
.bind('dragstop',   function(){ $("#divId").text("drag ended");});
```

Comment: That is the correct use as written in the documentation: http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/

Comment: In the jQuery documentation, true, but why doesn't jQuery use the 'dragend' event, which as far as I can tell is in the HTML5 standard while 'dragstop' is not?

Comment: @JonCarter because the standards committee of javascript are a bunch of haphazard crackpots, who implement specs on a whim and rush them through.jQuery has always been about maximizing productivity and a means disambiguate the various flaws and discrepancies in the implementation(s) that have arisen as a result of this culture.to summarize, `dragstart` and `dragstop` are logical naming conventions. in fact, i found this answer by googling `jQuery dragstart dragstop` because i didn't know what the name of the events were and needed to double check.

Answer (score 0):

**In JavaScript and jQuery**, when the user stops dragging the cursor, the event fired is: `dragend`.

**In jQuery UI**, after calling `.draggable();`, when the user stops dragging the cursor, the event fired then becomes: `dragstop`.  ([Small demo showing that dragstop no longer works when `.draggable()` isn't called.](https://jsbin.com/qiwuvez/edit?html,css,js,console,output))

*Documentation...*

**JavaScript** - `dragend`: Searching google for this produces about 100,000 search results, so this is likely what you'll be using. Source: [**MDN Web Docs: Document: dragend Event**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/dragend_event)

**jQuery UI** - `dragstop`: Searching for "jQuery UI Dragstop" produces only 5,000 search results at Google as of August, 2020.  I can barely find any mention of it, but it is there in the **[Official jQuery UI Documentation: Draggable Widget](https://api.jqueryui.com/1.11/draggable/)**.