# JQuery: Changing the DOM on dragstart event fires dragend immediately?

Tags: javascript, jquery

i came across a bug for Chrome and Opera and i would like to know if its known and if so, is there a solution?

If i change the DOM on the dragstart event it immediately fires the dragend event?! Is this a bug or is there some reason behind it? Only happens in Chrome and Opera. Firefox works.

I appreciate every answer.

```js
$('body').on({
      dragstart: function(e) {
        
        dragProfilefieldSrcElformid = $(this).attr("data-profilefieldid-formid");
        e.dataTransfer = e.originalEvent.dataTransfer;
        e.dataTransfer.effectAllowed = 'move';
        e.dataTransfer.setData('text/html', $(this).attr("data-profilefieldid"));
        
        // Changing the DOM, fires the dragend Event in Chrome?
        $("#plugin_loginlogout_pfcontainer_" + dragProfilefieldSrcElformid).find(".plugin_loginlogout_pf_entryfield").addClass("highlight"); // This doesn't work in Chrome and Opera, but in Firefox
      },
      dragend: function() {
        console.log("dragend");
      }
      ".plugin_loginlogout_pf");
```

Edit:

Putting the DOM Change in a setTimeout Function seems to solve the problem!

Comment: Can someone confirm that this is a bug or normal behavior? It seems to affect Firefox too.

Comment: @thelolcat Possible dup of http://stackoverflow.com/a/15114255/2646526?  JQuery docs talk about using `dragstop`, not `dragend`.  So there is no defined behavior in jQuery for handling `dragend`.

Comment: is `$("#plugin_loginlogout_pfcontainer_" + dragProfilefieldSrcElformid)` inside your dragged element or on somewhere else?

Comment: What is `".plugin_loginlogout_pf"` after  `dragend` function?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It seems that different browsers manifest different behaviors towards *long running* operations.

JavaScript has a single thread that runs all of your instructions in the same queue. Each queue item is run in sequence and once the item has finished execution, the next item (*from the queue*) is grabbed and run.

The culprit for long running operation is the change you try to bring to the DOM (*which I assume is preceded by a heavy search using `find()` that will run the DOM manipulation for each matched element*).

> What happens as you drag the element is that, all lines of code in the `dragstart` handler, and as you stop dragging, the `dragend` handler are pushed to the message queue respectively in order to be executed serially. However the *DOM manipulation* is taking more time (probably a few milliseconds more) to execute than the execution of the `dragend` handler before you stop dragging, and therefore, it appears as if the `dragend` fired way too soon.

**Note:** Sometimes block(s) of code ***create a new event*** and hence are pushed to the end of the browser event queue (*or maybe somewhere after the item that's being run*), resulting in a later execution. (I suppose the nature of it differs from browser to browser.)

The *DOM manipulation* part of your code *might* face such an issue in Chrome and Opera, though I'm not sure.

## The `setTimeout(fn, 0)` Trick

The workaround for such situations is to *wrap* the long running operation block in a `setTimeout` function with `0` time.

(You can think of this as telling the browser to *run* the part of your code, in ***no time at all!***, not literally though.)

Once a block of code has done execution, the browser will search for the available items waiting to be run, and the ones with `setTimeout` or `setInterval` will be pushed to the queue upon first available moment.

In your particular case, the trick is that `setTimeout` *defers* the execution of DOM change to a later time (*at least `0` seconds*) than the `dragend` event handler, thereby giving the impression as if the `dragend` event fired after the DOM change.

There is a great post by @DVK [***here***](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4575011/1742333) explaining *why `setTimeout(fn, 0)` is sometimes useful*. Do check the [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/C2YBE/31/) by him (in Chrome) as well.

### Update

As pointed by @MojoJojo and @Pradeep, it seems that Webkit browsers (older versions of Chrome in particular) have an issue with `drag` events. However, I tried to reproduce the bug in Chrome Version 47.0.2526.106 (newest version as of 11th January 2016), and the `drag` events fired without any irregularities.

**Anyway, even if there was a bug, the `setTimeout` trick still applies as a proper workaround for the issue.**

Comment: setTimeout() workaround is buggy in Firefox, see my answer for a more stable alternative.

Answer (score 3):

Just try putting your DOM manipulation in **drag** event of dragstart instead :)

Comment: Can confirm that manipulating the DOM (in the subtree of the currently being dragged element) triggers a `dragabort` within modern Chrome at least & Vue@2. Moving the manipulation to the `drag` event helped, thanks! We were changing the DOM (basically hiding elements -not via opacity though!- to make drag and drop operations easily in a possibly long list/tree w/ possibly deep expanded items) in `dragstart`. Adding another operation to maintain `state` (basically a flag to signify that a drag is ongoing) within `drag`, as well as `dragleave` & `dragabort` was the missing piece of the puzzle.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a glitch/bug or else we can say this is how browser work since we are doing the DOM manipulations which may lead to repaint the entire DOM again,manipuating DOM in the dragStart event is causing this problem,shift DOM manipulation to dragEnter may solve the issue.

The other solution could be setting the setTimeout which you already mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

This does seem like a an issue in Chrome
https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/?fromgroups=#!msg/chromium-bugs/YHs3orFC8Dc/ryT25b7J-NwJ

What version of Chrome are you using?

Answer (score 0):

without jquery works

```
    var draggable = document.getElementById('draggable'),
      test = document.getElementById('test');

    document.addEventListener("dragend", function(event) {
      // reset the transparency
      console.log('dragend');
    }, false);

    draggable.addEventListener('dragstart', function(event) {
      test.style.color = 'red';
      draggable.style.backgroundColor = 'gray';
    }, false);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nwkv75ot/4/

Answer (score 0):

I found the setTimeout() workaround to be very buggy in Firefox. For example, when you immediately release the mouse button after dragging, the context within the *dragstart* might be no longer accesible and the script can crash. Especially when used in combination with the *dragend* event.

I created the following procedure which gave much more reliability to my script:

```
$('html').on('dragstart', '.somelement', function(e){

    // Bind 'drag' event only once (gets triggered every 350ms)
    $('html').one('drag', function(){
         // modify DOM here
    });
});

$('html').on('dragend', '.somelement', function(e){

    // Edge might fire 'dragend' before executing the 'drag' event within 'dragstart'
    $('html').unbind('drag');

});
```