# Javascript dragend event fired immediatly after dragstart

Tags: javascript, vue.js, drag-and-drop, draggable

I've an important bug that is causing me a lot of damage.

I've done a form generator component in Vue.

It's composed by draggable area, with draggable items with a friendly appearence: short answer, long answer, numeric answer, radio/checkbox answer...

There is also a drop zone, in which I can drop these draggable items, in order to be pushed to a object and compose that form preview.

This is a little introduction of my end goal. That works fine, I've no problem with any event BUT... I've a bug in the draggable area. Sometimes, I can't establish a path to define what is going on. I repeat, sometimes, when I start to drag and the dragstart event is fired (I put a console.log in that event), the dragend event is fired immediately while I've the primary button still pushed (I also see that event in a console.log I put in the dragend handler).

I can't reproduce it. And it doesn't mind which field type I drag from the draggable area. I've seen that there was a Chrome bug, but it's fixed (I think!).

My Chrome version is: *Version 78.0.3904.108 (Official Build) (64-bit)* and the problems came with versions before (I repeat, I think).

I'm going to show some pseudo-code of what I'm doing.

**DraggableArea.vue**

```
<template lang='pug'>
  #draggable-area
    ul
      draggable-item(
        v-for='draggableField in draggableFields'
        :fieldInfoToBeDropped='draggableField.fieldInfoToBeDropped'
      )

</template>
```

**DraggableItem.vue**

```
<template lang='pug'>
  li(
    draggable='true'
    @dragstart.stop='handleDragstart'
    @dragend.stop='handleDragend'
    @drop.stop='handleDrop
</template>

export default {
  ...

  methods: {
    handleDragstart(e) {
      const fieldInfoToBeDropped = this.fieldInfoToBeDropped // this is an object which contains the information that drop zone will handle to create the field in the form object
      try {
        console.log('DraggableItem, handleDragstart event:', e)
        setTimeout(() => { this.$el.classList.add('drag') }, 10)
        e.dataTransfer.clearData()
        const fieldObjectStr = JSON.stringify(fieldInfoToBeDropped)
        e.dataTransfer.setData('fieldObject', fieldObjectStr)
      } catch (err) {
        console.log('DraggableItem, handleDragstart error:', err)
        this.$el.classList.remove('drag')
        e.dataTransfer.clearData()
        e.preventDefault()
      }
    },

    handleDragend(e) {
      console.log('DraggableItem: dragend fires')
      this.$el.classList.remove('drag')
      e.dataTransfer.clearData()
    },

    handleDrop(e) {
      this.handleDragend(e)
    }

  }
```

An example of fieldInfoToBeDropped. It changes the id (that is generated dynamically, the componentType, and the iconName).

```
{
 componentType:"text",
 name:"",
 description:"",
 iconName:"text",
 id:"field_1575448385646rgzh6hhh6",
 mandatory:true
}
```

I haven't notice that the problem exists in other browsers but I haven't tried as I do in Chrome.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I solved this.

I hide some content while an item is dragged, so window height is less than original. That means that scroll appears and dissapear, moving my cursor and firing drop event.

**It only happens in Google Chrome**

Comment: Hey! I'm faced with this issue too. How you managed to fix it?

Comment: Sorry for the late response. Basically the resize event of the browser was triggered because on drag, I updated some styles that modifies the height of the screen and therefore the dragged event was released.

Comment: Can confirm that DOM manipulation within a `dragstart` event handler triggers a native/browser-issued automatic `dragabort`, one has to move anything modifying the DOM (subtree) of the currently being dragged element to the more generic `drag` event handler, as mentioned in this related question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/28408720/132735